# "dropdown-toggle" down on default

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am using bootstrap to have a side navigation bar in mijn application. I would like the dropdown menu's to be open by default, but I can't work it out...

My code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/') }}">Home of   {{ Auth::user()->name }}<span style="font-size:16px;"></span></a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Input <span class="caret"></span><span style="font-size:16px;"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu forAnimate" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/dashboard/input') }}">Form</a></li>                                
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >Results <span class="caret"></span><span style="font-size:16px;"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/dashboard/result/overview') }}">Results</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li><a href="{{ url('/') }}">Tools<span></span></a></li>

                    <li><a href="{{ url('/documentation') }}">Documentation<span></span></a></li>
                    @endif
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

```
<li class="dropdown">
```

to

```
<li class="dropdown open">
```

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks :D

Comment: It's my pleasure :)